# Any idea when the next candidates will move forward?

Tags: support, area-51, beta-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did web-apps go to beta and gaming did not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55576/why-did-web-apps-go-to-beta-and-gaming-did-not)

Can we have a more specific estimate on the time when the next Area 51 candidates will enter the beta phase?

So far all we know is ["one at a time"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55576/why-did-web-apps-go-to-beta-and-gaming-did-not/55597#55597), but what does it mean exactly?

- Only one private beta at a time?
- Only one beta in general, at a time?
- None of the above, it will depend on the stability of the current beta?

Comment: Also... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55729/is-pro-webmasters-being-throttled-closed

Comment: @Jon Seigel: Please look at the question. It is completely different from the one you've marked as a duplicate. Please READ THE QUESTION before marking it as a duplicate. YES I AM SHOUTING AT YOU.

Comment: @Kinopiko: Voting to close as a duplicate says "This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic" -- David's answer answers your question... again. They're doing them one at a time; presumably the next one will start when enough bugs have been squashed. Please be patient. When those proposals move to the next step, I'm assuming you'll be sent an e-mail, meaning you'll be the first to know.

Comment: @Jon - I agree with you here. @Kino, Seriously? Need some valium or something? I have a few emails in my spam folder that could help you out.

Comment: You didn't quite specify that you're looking for a time scale. "When the previous one is completed" is a legitimately complete answer to the question as you have phrased it, and that is the essence of David's answer. So, quite frankly, your question, as it is phrased, is quite a duplicate. I would vote to close too, but you've specified in your comments that you want a hard date from the team. As such, I am withholding my vote since I have this knowledge. I don't think you needed to shout and curse, though.

Comment: I agree this is not a duplicate of those questions, I am also interested in official or guesses responses to this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56020/estimate-on-new-beta-site

Comment: @Kino - your tone in comments was inviting me to vote to close as noise and pointless. But the question in itself is legitimate, and the person who asked it is finally not important. This is why I reworded it, to make it more clear in what we want to know.

Comment: @Kinopiko, I'm inclined to think that you're potentially trying to make a good point, but the sarcasm and hostility in your comments undermines your goal - helping someone who starts with a different view to see what you're getting at.

Comment: I am one of the 3 (current) close votes. Now that @Gnoupi has reworded it to make it truly different (in a way where the answers are no longer duplicative), if this still ends up closed, I will vote to reopen.

Comment: Okay, I agree with that.

Comment: As I've said, this isn't a duplicate of the other question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first ones will go a bit slow so we can work bugs out of the process. In the future we plan to attach dates on Area 51 so everyone is clear when exactly things will happen.